# window.location.href is not being modified

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

I have following code

```
    var windowHref = window.location.href;
    if (windowHref.includes('/project/')) {
        var splitURL = windowHref.split('/');
        window.location.href = windowHref.substring(0, windowHref.indexOf('#/project')) + '?projectId=' + splitURL[splitURL.length - 2];
    }
    window.location.reload(true);
```

Before execution of above code, the value of `window.location.href` is

`https://localhost:44301/default.aspx#/project/16a76abd-5b5b-4c63-822f-2bfd7f133adc/home`

and after execution, I want its value to be like

`https://localhost:44301/default.aspx?projectId=16a76abd-5b5b-4c63-822f-2bfd7f133adc`

but when the line

`window.location.href = windowHref.substring(0,windowHref.indexOf('#/project')) + '?projectId=' + splitURL[splitURL.length - 2];`

is executed, the `window.location.href` remains unchanged.

And the result of

`windowHref.substring(0,windowHref.indexOf('#/project')) + '?projectId=' + splitURL[splitURL.length - 2];`

is

`https://localhost:44301/default.aspx?projectId=16a76abd-5b5b-4c63-822f-2bfd7f133adc`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some PHP, or JavaScript, working with that `$_GET` URL, that changes it?

Comment: No, there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest remove the line `window.location.reload(true);` as it's unnecessary to redirect the client to new page when using window.location.href

```
var href =  window.location.href; 
var index = href.indexOf('#/project/');
if(index!==-1){  
   var splitURL = href.substring(index,href.length).replace('#/project/','?projectId=').split('/');
   window.location.href = splitURL[0];
}
```

Comment: I need this to redirect to the modified URL. Can you suggest me someway to redirect to the required URL e.g. `https://localhost:44301/default.aspx?projectId=16a76abd-5b5b-4c63-822f-2bfd7f133adc`

Comment: window.location.href will redirect to URL you assign to it. so basically your code should work.. I assume if you remove the window.location.reload line, and if your URL contains '/project/' in it your code should do what you are looking for.. 
plus based on information on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp to use "includes" function of JS string, your browser must supports it.

Comment: Even after removing it, the `window.location.href`is not assigned new value.

Comment: I added a piece of code to my answer, can you please try it? and if it still doesn't work please add a console.log('Reached Here') inside the `if(index!==-1)`  to see if you really get into the IF block or not. Also please post here if you see any error in console log.

Comment: Its working now. I removed the `window.location.reload(true);` and just executed the whole block.
Although I can't see the newly assigned value to `window.location.href` after the line `window.location.href = windowHref.substring(0,windowHref.indexOf('#/project')) + '?projectId=' + splitURL[splitURL.length - 2]` is executed.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and yes.. the reason is window.location.href forces the browser to redirect to assigned value( URL ) , therefore page breaks and tries to render new URL